# PhpStorm git integration doesn't show "compare" menu item

Tags: git, phpstorm

Very weird. Since today morning the menu items have changed in the Git integration panel.

Let's say I'm on branch "develop" and want to compare another branch. Normally the menu shows a "Compare" item, which now has been replaced by "Compare with...". I'm not sure what I changed on the repository to cause this.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Wording has changed from "Compare" to "Compare With...". I'm having the same menu entries. That's most likely some undocumented change in IDE.

Comment: Ok, I really thought the functionality also is different. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll move the comment into a reply:
That's just a wording change on IDE side.